# Correlation Function and Generating Functional in QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, path-integral, correlation-functions, partition-function

[Peskin and Schroeder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201503972) (1995, p.82 and p.292) define the two-point correlation function of a $\phi^4$ theory as

$$\langle \Omega|T\{\phi(x)\phi(y)\}|\Omega\rangle\tag{4.10}$$

and the generating functional $Z[J]$ of a $\phi^4$ theory as

$$Z[J] \equiv \int \mathcal{D}\phi \; \textrm{exp} \left[i\int d^4x(\mathcal{L}+J\phi)\right].\tag{9.42}$$

What are the corresponding definitions for the correlation function and the generating functional in QED?

Answer (score 1):

In QED the situation is very similar, in particular, you have
\begin{equation}
Z[J^{\mu}, \bar{J}, J]= \int D A_{\mu} D\psi D \bar{\psi} \, e^{i (S_{QED}- \int d^4x J^{\mu} A_{\mu}+\bar{J} \psi+ \bar{\psi} J })
\end{equation}
you can obtain all correlations functions in the same way.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please provide the corresponding definition for the correlation function as well and elaborate a bit further on the terms? A reference would also help a lot!

Comment: @Floyd: Peskin & Schroeder is your reference.